# How to get points in bounding box by degrees for map

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I have some concerns about working of BOX3D PostGIS function. I tried to find places in square -158.721365889063 66.09275164148659, 154.608712235937 52.56807548751039(degrees). But this where statement

```
    some_place.point && SetSRID('BOX3D(-158.721365889063 66.09275164148659,
    154.608712235937 52.56807548751039)'::box3d,4326)
```

returns places in the biggest of two possible squares.

When I change order of angles or use 'xmin ymin,xmax ymax' order, I got the same result.

Also I used

```
     ST_Contains( SetSRID( ST_MakeBox2D( 
      ST_Point(143.930001298437,66.82980906973742), 
      ST_Point(-145.757498701563,51.37699768868392) ), 4326 ), some_place.point)
```

with the same result.

How can I do it for some specific order of angle's points?

P.S. 
I got bounds from google map api.

Comment: I am confused by the data in this question.  Could you please explain why it makes sense that 66... could be a `ymin` value while the *smaller* number, 52..., could be `ymax`?

Comment: @whuber I wrote that I tried right order. It's not ymax it's only one of the possibilities that I use, but I got the same answer for any order of angles' coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

PostGIS has the function ST_Shift_Longitude(). If I understand your question, you want the BBOX to be between 143E and 145W ?
So something like (not tested):

```
SELECT ST_Contains(
ST_Shift_Longitude(
GeomFromText('POLYGON((143 51, 143 66, -145 66, -145 51, 143 51))', 4326)),
ST_Shift_Longitude(GeomFromText('POINT(144 52)', 4326))
)
```

should return '1' (true), 
But if you set the POINT as 'POINT(142 52)' it should return '0'.

Comment: I don't know how I miss your answer. ST_Shift_Longitude is very helpful for me. Really, thanks.

Comment: My quick view was wrong.. It doesn't work :( You query return 't'. But it can not be true.

Comment: Could you give us some more specific details of what you're trying to achieve, and explain why "it can not be true". What query did to run, what results did you get, and what did you expect that came out wrong?